# how do fire trigger ? first element

Tags: jquery, triggers

I have this simple script

**html code**

```
<div id='div1'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#gone'>gone</a></li>
        <li><a href='#gtwo'>gtwo</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id='div2'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#g1'>g1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#g2'>g2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**js code**

```
init();
function init(){
    target = $('#div1').find('ul');

    target.on('click','a',function(){
        alert ($(this).attr('href'));
    });

    target.trigger('click');
}
```

how do fire trigger ? first element that would be with href #gone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign a unique id to each anchor tag and can use like

```
<div id='div1'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#gone' id='gone' >gone</a></li>
        <li><a href='#gtwo' id='gtwo'>gtwo</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And javascript would be like.

```
$("#gone").trigger("click");
```

And binding click event like this

```
$("#gone").bind("click",function(event){
//your code.
});
```

If your ul li are dynamic then you can use like :

```
$('#div1 ul li').first().find("a").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `first-child` ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BK8nw/2)):

```
init();
function init(){
    target = $('#div1 ul');
    target.on('click','a',function(){
        alert ($(this).attr('href'));
    });

    $('li:first-child a', target).trigger('click');
}
```